# two different arrays from the same API call updating each other

Tags: arrays, angular, api, filter

I have a weird situation. I have two objects:

```
sessionBase: ISessionViewWrapperModel = <ISessionViewWrapperModel>{};
sessionDisplay: ISessionViewWrapperModel = <ISessionViewWrapperModel>{};
```

I make an api call and populate both:

```
    this.appService.getCourtSessionWithHearings(Number(this.apiUser?.Id), this.sessionId).subscribe((response) => {
      this.sessionDisplay = response;
      this.sessionBase = response;
    });
```

Then I have a toggle button that if "on", I filter the "hearings" array in the  sessionDisplay object. If off, it resets the entire sessionDisplay object to the sessionBase object:

```
    if (event.checked) {
      this.sessionDisplay.Hearings = this.sessionDisplay.Hearings.filter(x => x.IsCancelled === false && x.IsContinuance === false && x.IsReset === false);
    } else {
      this.sessionDisplay = this.sessionBase;
    }
```

the weird thing is that once I filter the hearings array on the "sessionDisplay" object, the hearings on the "sessionBase" object are also filtered. The only way I can make it work is to do two separate calls to the api:

```
    this.appService.getCourtSessionWithHearings(Number(this.apiUser?.Id), this.sessionId).subscribe((response) => {
      this.sessionBase = response;
    });

    this.appService.getCourtSessionWithHearings(Number(this.apiUser?.Id), this.sessionId).subscribe((response) => {
      this.sessionDisplay = response;
    });
```

it is like the response from the api call is impacted by the filter.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Basically, I am trying to avoid a round-trip to the server by having the original object separate from the display object since filtering creates a new array and there is no way to reset it.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It sounds like a reference / value problem. I don't think you need two api call. Instead try to create a copy without reference (`{...this.sessionBase}`) or if it is not only one level deep, then with deep cloning (`JSON.stringify(this.sessionBase)`). Or if this doesn't work, then copy the response without reference.

Comment: Hope you don't find this irrelevant but do you actually need two objects? `this.sessionDisplay` and `this.sessionBase` are both equal to `response` and with the code you shared, `If off, it resets the entire sessionDisplay object to the sessionBase object` seems redundant.

Comment: What I am trying to do is allow for filtering/unfiltering the model in my view. Once you apply a filter it creates a new instance of the object. In order to get the original I would have to make another trip to the server, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @steveareeno, in this such case generally you create the sessionDisplay in component using some like `this.sessionDisplay=this.filter?this.sessionBase.filter(...):this.sessionBase` instead of equal in the subscription of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by derstauner, I found the solution. When making the api call I use Object.assign and it works.

```
    this.appService.getCourtSessionWithHearings(Number(this.apiUser?.Id), this.sessionId).subscribe((response) => {
      this.sessionBase = response;
      this.sessionDisplay =  Object.assign({}, response); 

    });
```

then in my toggle funtion I also use Object.assign:

```
  hideInactive(event: MatSlideToggleChange): void {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.sessionDisplay.Hearings = this.sessionDisplay.Hearings.filter(x => x.IsCancelled === false && x.IsContinuance === false && x.IsReset === false);
    } else {
      this.sessionDisplay = Object.assign({}, this.sessionBase);
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the tip!